# Why is our infoPath forms server very slow or very fast with same InfoPath web form?

Tags: forms, performance, infopath

WE have enterprise 2010 on a set of servers 3 front ends, tons of RAM.  We use IE-9 exclusively.  The issue is that sometimes the same web based InfoPath form opens very fast and sometimes opens very slow.  By slow I mean one time the form might take up to 1 or 2 minutes by fast I mean the same form opening in a couple of  seconds.   This has nothing to do with the design of the form other than larger more complex forms take more minutes to open than smaller less complex forms but all forms open so slow as to be unacceptable to the user.  They can open both fast or slow within  the same minute.  On our 2007 server they open just fine.  Originally we didn't have this issue.  I don't know whether it was an update, IE 9 or what.  Any suggestions on what it might be or how we might diagnose this issue are welcome.  thanks -dave

Comment: I'm seeing comments like uncheck "automatically detect proxy settings" in IE 9 and some commands that may or may not have effect but forgot to mention that if we create a new web form using the "New" button on the InfoPath library menu bar it always opens up instantly.  What might different about opening up a form as the .xml file from the library as opposed to opening up a new form from the menu bar>?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "random" performance issues like this when the Internet Explorer's "Automatically detect settings" option is selected.  See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220902).  If possible in your environment, you might try disabling this on a test machine to see if this helps.

Comment: good thought and thank you.  I recall some mention of how this "Automaically detect...something" can result in a prolonged search back through the net to find the proxy.  I think it was in reference to slow context menu rendering on right click.  Thanks for the lead and I'll look into it with our IT guys.  Unfortunately our IE9 settings are governed centrally and if this is the cause it may be hard to get them to push the change to desktops.